# How to freeze part of the tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to implement the pruning algorithms in Tensorflow. In order to do this I need not only to mask the weight during the pruning stage, but keep some entries of this tensor frozen to zero, during the consequent training.

Like I had (`[0, 0]` and `[1, 1]` entries masked):

```
[[0 1.3 2], [1.34 0 2.3]]
```

And after several batches I expect to still have zeros on
positions `[0, 0]` and `[1, 1]` .

There is a solution proposed here [How to stop gradient for some entry of a tensor in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364985/how-to-stop-gradient-for-some-entry-of-a-tensor-in-tensorflow). But seems like it works only for T`ensorFlow` v1, because the masked entries of the variable were updated after calling the `fit` method.

It is possible to create special class of `Optimizer` that will have redefined `apply_gradients` method, where the gradient will be multiplied by mask after each backward pass, but this solution seems to be rather inconvenient and one has redefine multiple optimizers - `Adam`, `RMSProp`, whatever.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298326/freeze-some-variables-scopes-in-tensorflow-stop-gradient-vs-passing-variables

Comment: @NVSAbhilash it is solution to a different problem - freeze backward pass along some path in a graph. In my case, the gradient propagates through the tensor, but only for elements where `mask=1`

Answer (score 0):

Could Tensorflow [Model Optimization](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization) be what you are looking for?

It already has implementations for [pruning](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning), which works similarly to the masking technique you described ([pruning_impl.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/blob/master/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/sparsity/keras/pruning_impl.py)).

Comment: actually, I wanted to make some extensions of the algorithms, available here :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there is a more clever solution, but the actual way to do this, and how it is done in [tfmot](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/api_docs/python/tfmot/sparsity/keras/prune_low_magnitude) is to *multiply* the weight by mask of zeros and ones after each forward pass.

Say one has tensor:

```
[[0 1.3 2], [1.34 0 2.3]]
```

And zeros at positions `[0, 0]` and `[1, 1]` need to be preserved.

Then, for every operation one needs to multiply this tensor by the following mask:

```
[[0 1 1], [1 0 1]]
```

This will do the job, since the gradient will not flow through these entries.